# Open file and get file path

Tags: python, pandas, tkinter

I'm trying to create a button to browse file and copy that file to a Master file and my code as below:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog

def get_file_path():
    global file_path
    file_path= filedialog.askopenfilename(title = "Select A File", filetypes = (("xlsx", "*.xlsx"), ("xls", "*.xls"), ("xlsm", "*.xlsm"), ("All Files", "*.*")))
    l1 = Label(window, text = file_path).pack()

window = Tk()
b1 = Button(window, text = "Open File", command = get_file_path).pack()
window.mainloop()
def close_window():
    window.destroy()
print(file_path)
import openpyxl as xl

path1 = ("r'" and file_path)
path2 = (r'C:\Users\...\Write_Data.xlsx')
wb1 = xl.load_workbook(filename=path1)
ws1 = wb1["BASEL_LN_CTR"]
wb2 = xl.load_workbook(filename=path2)
ws2 = wb2["Loan Data"]
for row in ws1:
    for cell in row:
        ws2[cell.coordinate].value = cell.value
wb2.save(path2)
```

Everything is working well for me but I have to close window manually to print file_path. I would like to know that there is any way to close window aucomatically. I used `destroy()` but it not worked.

Comment: ```.mainloop()``` is basically like while loop which keeps the window running. You can use ```.withdraw()``` to hide the main window, and ```deiconify()```, to reveal the window

Comment: how did you use `destroy()` ? Maybe you used it in wrong place.

Comment: you should use `window.destroy()` inside function `get_file_path`. OR you should create button `Close` with `command=close_window`. You never use `close_window()` so it can't works

Comment: @furas: I think I will create Close button with close command as your suggestion. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You created `close_window()` but you never use it.

You could create another button to run it (or to run directly `window.destroy`)

```
window = tk.Tk()

b1 = tk.Button(window, text="Open File", command=get_file_path).pack()
b2 = tk.Button(window, text="Close", comman=window.destroy).pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Or you should run it directly in `get_file_path()`

```
def get_file_path():
    global file_path
    
    file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(title="Select A File", filetypes = (("xlsx", "*.xlsx"), ("xls", "*.xls"), ("xlsm", "*.xlsm"), ("All Files", "*.*")))
    if file_path: # empty when pressed `Cancel`
        #tk.Label(window, text=file_path).pack()
        window.destroy()
```

Comment: Thank you, I have another question. When I change 'file_path' to another name like file_name; file_path_1... then error come that said name '' is not defined. What should I do?

Comment: What I want is make more button to copy others data from others workbook to paste in one file.

Comment: I know what problem is, just restart the kernel and it worked with new name.

Comment: you have to change `file_path` in ALL places - and error should show you where you forgot to change name

Comment: as I remeber `askopenfilename` should have option to select many files - so you could use one window (and one button) to select many paths. Eventually you should create list and `all_paths.append(file_path)` when you select it in `askopenfilename` and this way you could also use one button with one `askopenfilename` to select many files.

Comment: My problem is that each file has a different format, so I just want to create each button to find a separate file and paste it into the specified sheets.